# expanding parentheses gives undesirable indentation in neovim

Tags: neovim

This post is not about curly brackets. It is about **parentheses**.

I couldn't find a solution on how to expand parentheses with my ideal indentation.

### What happens now with expanding parentheses

**Before**

```
(|)
```

**Input**

```
<CR>
```

**After**

```
(
    |
    )
```

### What I want

**Before**

```
(|)
```

**Input**

```
<CR>
```

**After**

```
(
    |
)
```

I have delimitMate installed, but I don't think this is delimitMate's problem because it produces the same output without delimitMate. Yes, I experimented it.

The closest I've gotten was with `filetype indent off`, which successfully aligns the closing parenthesis with the opening one. However, the cursor's position ends up where I don't want it to be.

### What happens with the filetype option and delimitMate

**Before**

```
(|)
```

**Input**

```
<CR>
```

**After**

```
(
|
)
```

### What heppens with the filetype option and without delimitMate

**Before**

```
(|)
```

**Input**

```
<CR>
```

**After**

```
 (
|)
```

Ideally, I want a solution with delimitMate installed, but I think a solution without delimitMate will be a good foundation to solve this with delimitMate. So, I want to hear any solution to this with or without delimitMate.

Comment: Note that this depends on your filetype (for example it happens with Python, but not vim) -- and also happen with `v_=` (although it can be inconsistent). Try `set indentexpr=` and/or `set cindent cino=m1`

Comment: That didn't do anything.

Comment: Also check `smartindent`, `autoindent`, etc., and decide if those are set to the correct values. Frankly this type of thing is an issue in most "auto delimiter" style plugins—it's probably a corner case. The plugin authors might be able to help. Otherwise, you might want to make a mapping that does what you want

Answer (score 1):

I kind of solved the problem.(There might be a better way.)

Here is what I did as a Rust programmer.

1. I installed [rust.vim](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.vim) plugin.
2. I found a [pending pull request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.vim/pull/444) for the plugin.
3. I added the code manually from that pull request to see how it works.

It gave me the indentation.